# How to put dynamic id in href attribute in anchor tag?

Tags: reactjs

Quick question regarding putting a dynamic id inside anchor tag.

```
<div className="portal">
<span>Visit portal</span><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="../all_rms/rmspage.html?ID="+{this.state.selectedPlace.id} > 
<i className="fa fa-external-link-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

I m getting error as `Parsing error: Unexpected token`. Thanks

Comment: href={ "../all_rms/rmspage.html?ID=" + this.state.selectedPlace.id }

Comment: @AshokGujjar your worked too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
href={`..all_rms/rmspage.html?ID=${this.state.selectedPlace.id}`}
```